# oracle giving PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number error

Tags: java, sql, plsql, oracle11g

My table is :

```
EmpNo   Ename   Job   MGR   HireDate    Sal
1        ABC    DPS   JOO   01-10-2002  2000
2        BCD    LPS   KOL   03-11-2005  2300
3        KOLD   MPS   BOR   13-03-2012  2400
```

I am trying to import above table from csv file into pre defined table in oracle database. Below is the code(pl sql code) to import above table.

Code :

```
Drop table emp_tbl
create table emp_tbl
( EmpNo Number,
EName varchar2(15),
Job Varchar2(15),
MGR Varchar2(30),
HireDate Date,
Sal Number
);


create or replace procedure read_file_proc
Is
  f_line varchar2(2000);
  f utl_file.file_type ;
  f_dir varchar2(250);
  fname varchar2(50);
  comma1 Number;
  comma2 Number;
  comma3 Number;
  comma4 Number;
  comma5 Number;
  f_empno emp_tbl.empno%type;
  f_ename emp_tbl.ename%type;
  f_job emp_tbl.job%type;
  f_mgr emp_tbl.MGR%type;
  f_hiredate emp_tbl.hiredate%type;
  f_sal emp_tbl.sal%type;
Begin
  dbms_output.put_line('At Begin');
  fname := 'Emp_tbl.csv';
  f := utl_file.fopen('UTL_FILE_DIR', fname, 'R');
  dbms_output.put_line('Before loop');
  loop 
    Begin
      Utl_file.get_line(f, f_line);
      --dbms_output.put_line(f_line);
    exception
      when no_data_found then
      exit;
    end;
    comma1 := instr(f_line,',', 1, 1);
    comma2 := instr(f_line,',', 1, 2);
    comma3 := instr(f_line,',', 1, 3);
    comma4 := instr(f_line,',', 1, 4);
    comma5 := instr(f_line,',', 1, 5);
    f_empno := to_number(substr(f_line, 1, comma1 -1 ));
    f_ename := substr(f_line, comma1 + 1, comma2 - comma1 - 1);
    f_job := substr(f_line, comma2 + 1, comma3 - comma2 - 1);
    f_mgr := substr(f_line, comma3 + 1, comma4 - comma3 - 1);
    f_hiredate := to_date(substr(f_line, comma4 + 1, comma5 - comma4 - 1), 'dd-mon,-yyyy');
    f_sal := to_number(substr(f_line, comma5 + 1));
    insert into emp_tbl values(f_empno, f_ename, f_job, f_mgr,  f_hiredate, f_sal);

  end loop;
  utl_file.fclose(f);
  --commit;
end read_file_proc;
```

But upon running in sql developer i am receiving below error :

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number
>   conversion error ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.READ_FILE_PROC", line 36
>   ORA-06512: at line 2

But when i am entering values directly(by using insert query) for f_empno, f_hiredate, f_salary... it is working fine.

Can anybody please tell me Why i am getting above mentioned error.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : As asked the first row in CSV file appears as :

```
1,Akon,TSP,Navi,01-10-2002,2000
```

Comment: Please make your code more readable by using a good layout. It will help you when debugging. See my changes in your code, as example.

Comment: The result for f_empno is a varchar2 (f_empno is the only number variable). Try the same but use empno as varchar2 by creating the table. Then you will see the value used during the insert. Before you make it a stored procedure run the procedure not as a stored procedure and check the values (with dbms_output.put_line) before using on the insert statement

Comment: Please share a sample of the csv file

Comment: @wieseman ..thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @wieseman.... i have already declared f_empno as number in my table where i am importing the csv file data even while manipulating the substring  i am using to_number function to convert the varchar into number...but still error come in..

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz.. above Mytable is the same csv file data which i am trying to import. My real problem is ..on daily basis i received large csv file ..which need to import into a table ..so that i can prepare summary reports (for which i have written some sql code), so i want to automate the process of importing csv file into table. Also need to update some existing tables for creating historical data.

Comment: You are trying to import a file so what matter here is how the data looks in the file. Just copy the first rows of one of your files and put it in the question instead of table representation that has no meaning .P.s. as I wrote in my answer, they are much better ways to do it.

Comment: Row >>  1,Akon,TSP,Navi,01-10-2002,2000 ... i am newbie (pls let me know any other better way to import heavy csv files )

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz.. thanks  I got clue from your question. I have posted the answer below

Answer (score 1):

It seems the date format is wrong.

```
f_hiredate := to_date(substr(f_line, comma4 + 1, comma5 - comma4 - 1), 'dd-mon,-yyyy');
```

The right format is `dd-mm-yyyy`

P.s.
There are much better ways to do this.
If you have access to the server external table would be great.
From client side, SQL*Loader.
If you insist on Procedure - regular expression will serve you well.

Comment: @Dave,I need to see some data in order to determine the right format.

Answer (score -1):

thanks all for your response.

I have changed

```
f_hiredate := to_date(substr(f_line, comma4 + 1, comma5 - comma4 - 1), 'dd-mon,-yyyy');
```

to

```
f_hiredate := to_date(substr(f_line, comma4 + 1, comma5 - comma4 - 1), 'dd-mm-yyyy');
```

And actually my csv file was :

```
EmpNo,Ename,Job,MGR,HireDate,Sal
1,Akon,TSP,Navi,01-10-2002,2000
2,Anu,SSP,Man,03-11-2005,2300
```

The problem was the first row which contains the column names instead of data.

Comment: pl. justify the negative response.